# boost::iostream zlib compressing multiple files into one archive

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, compression, zlib

i'm having trouble packing a bunch of files into one archive. the boost docs are very limited on this topic and i've searched the web for several hours now, but i can't find a solution.

What i have so far:

```
boost::filesystem::ofstream ofsArchive("some.zip");
boost::iostreams::filtering_ostreambuf outFilter;
boost::iostreams::zlib_params zparam(boost::iostreams::zlib::default_compression);

try
{
    // set up the filter
    outFilter.strict_sync();
    outFilter.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor(zparam));
    outFilter.push(ofsArchive);


    for(each object of some kind)
    {
        // create a binary serialized file
        boost::filesystem::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios_base::binary); 
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive bin_oa( ofs ); 
        bin_oa << crazyObject;

        // here's where i'm stuck. how to add multiple files to the "some.zip"?
        boost::iostreams::copy(ofs, outputArchive);
    }
}
catch(boost::iostreams::zlib_error& e){...}
```

how do i add the files to the zip archive? the method provided obviously doesn't work, i just can't find anything on the subject in the docs or header files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

zlib does not implement the Zip file format, it just implements the stream compression used within Zip (see [the zlib FAQ](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq11)). To my knowledge (which I should warn you is by no means total), Boost does not include functionality to read or write Zip archives. There are libraries that do provide that functionality <s>of course, for example, [zziplib](http://zziplib.sourceforge.net) (note: the site appears to be down at the moment).</s>

Edit: Apparently, zziplib actually *can't* write Zip files, it can only read them. Still, I'm sure a little googling would turn up a library capable of writing the format.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is a bit old, but for people like me who see it years after.

There are a bunch of free librairies to write and read zip files in C (usable in C++ of course) :
- [infoZip](http://www.info-zip.org/) (last version seems to be really complete and safe, though it dates back in 2008);
- [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/index.html), much more recent, last version being only two months old.