# Zip directory in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, zip, compression

How can I zip directory in C++. I read this question: [How do I zip a directory of files using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505863/how-do-i-zip-a-directory-of-files-using-c) But I'd prefer a way that uses something like `gzip`, `zlib` and `boost`(because I do not want to add new libs to the project). Winapi-way is also acceptable (if it exists). And I do not want to start new process.

I would like a code sample. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want zip but you don't want to use any libraires?

Do you want to be bound by a particular licence - if so then simply copy all the code from zlib and the zip add-on into your own code.

If you can't use their licence then get the specs and write your own clean room implementation - make sure that you haven't seen the zlib or zip code base though.

The other alternative is to bundle a freely available zip command line client and call it with a system() call

edit: if you mean you are already using zlib then [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) does the directory stuff - it's usually included with zlib in the contrib directory

Comment: I believe he's already using `gzip`, `zlib` or `boost`, but doesn't want to add *other* libraries.

Comment: I did not mean that refuse zlib. Actually I want to use it, but I do not know how to use it to compress the directory. If you how this can be done using zlib, could you write?

Comment: I cannot use system() call, because I do not want to start new processes

Comment: @Loom - zlib itself doesn't do directories, you need minizip, see the edit. Sorry for the attitude you get a lot of beginner posts who say "I want to do X" but I don't want to use libraries because thats too difficult!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can use boost iostream which includes compression functionalities. Have a look at the documentation here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html</strike>

It seems that in fact in this case that won't work for a directory of files.

Comment: If possible, could you expand the answer? As I understand it, boost supports compression streams, not files. Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961155/boostiostream-zlib-compressing-multiple-files-into-one-archive/4961334#4961334

Comment: Ah, it seems you're right indeed. I have edited my post. My apologies. I had only used it before on streams and assumed it would work for files as well, but I can't find evidence that it does. If anyone else knows it will work, let me know as well. :)